# The spectrum of a product of rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $A$ be the product of a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of commutative rings, and  $c$ the canonical continuous map from the disjoint union $U$ of the spectra of the $A_i$ to the spectrum of $A$: 
$$
A:=\prod_{i\in I}\ A_i,\quad U:=\coprod_{i\in I}\ \text{Spec}(A_i),\quad c:U\to\text{Spec}(A).
$$

> Is the image of $c$ dense?

Let $f$ be a continuous map from $U$ to a quasi-compact space $X$.

> Is there a continuous map $F:\text{Spec}(A)\to X$ such that $F\circ c=f\ $?

[Diagram: 
$$
f:\coprod_{i\in I}\ \text{Spec}(A_i)\ \overset{c}{\to}\ \text{Spec}(A)\ \overset{F}{\to}\ X.]
$$

Comment: I suddenly have some doubt, is your quasi-compact space $X$ the underlying space of a scheme ?

Comment: Dear @QiL: What I had in mind was a general quasi-compact space, but answers to particular cases are more than welcome.

Comment: Dear Pierre-Yves, the answer is positive in the setting of schemes if $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$ is one point for all $i$, but you already known the result. In general, still in the setting of schemes, I strongly suspect the answer to be non, though I don't have a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of $c$ is dense if the $A_i$ are reduced. If $\mathrm{im}(c)$ is contained in some closed subset $V(f)$, then the latter contains the image of $V(\ker p_i)$ of the closed immersion $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$,  where $p_i : A\to A_i$ is the canonical projection. So $f\in \sqrt{\ker p_i}$ and the $i$-component $f_i$ of $f$ is nilpotent, hence equal to $0$. This being true for all $i$, we have $f=0$.

In general, if $f\in A$ is such that $f_i$ is nilpotent for all $i$, then the above reasonning shows that $V(f)$ contains the image of $c$. Now if there is such an $f$ which is not nilpotent, then $V(f)\ne \mathrm{Spec}A$ and the image of $c$ is *not dense*. For instance take $I=\mathbb N$, $A_i=\mathbb C[t_i]/(t_i^{i+1})$ and $f_i=\bar{t}_i$, then we have a counterexample.

The answer to the second part is negative **without the quasi-compactness assumption** on $X$. Just take $X=U$ and $f=\mathrm{Id}_U$. Then you would get a section $\mathrm{Spec}A\to U$ of $c$.

Consider the example $I=\mathbb N$, $A_i=\mathbb F_{p_i}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number (OK it is not the projection $p_i$ as above). Let $V_i=F^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec}(A_i))$. Then $\{ V_i\}_i$ is an open covering of $\mathrm{Spec}A$. For any principal open subset $D(f)$ contained in $V_i$, $p_i=0$ in $A_f$ because we have a homomorphism $A_i\to A_f$. Hence $p_if=0$ in $A$ (which is reduced). Projecting to $A_j$ for all $j\ne i$, we get $f_j=0$. Hence $D(f)$ is empty or equal to the singleton $x_i=\ker (A\to A_i)$. But it is well known by the theory of ultrafilters that $\mathrm{Spec}A$ is bigger than $\{ x_i\}_i$.

Comment: Dear QiL: Thanks a lot! I'll try to understand your answer... There is a first point I don't get. You write: "take $X=U$". But, it seems to me, $U$ is *not* quasi-compact (at least if $I$ is infinite and the $A_i$ nonzero). --- I think I understand the first part, and upvoted the answer (even if I don't understand yet the second part).

Comment: I convinced myself that the spectrum of the product of a family $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}K_i$ of fields is the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb N$. Since I often convince myself of things which are false, I'd like to know if the above statement is true.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: I am sorry, I missed the quasi-compact condition. The factorization exists when $\mathrm{Spec}A_i$ is reduced to one point for all $i$. I don't know for the general case.

Comment: Dear @QiL: fantastic answer! There are two points I don't get: 1) You write " The factorization exists when $Spec A_i $ is reduced to one point for all $i$ ". Haven't you just proved the opposite? 2) Suppose $f=(1,0,0,...)$; why is any $\mathfrak m \in D(f)$ equal to $x_1$?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, I meant the factorization doesn't exist if $X$ is not assumed to be quasi-compact. Sorry for being confusing. When the $A_i$ all have dimension $0$, the factorization exists when $X$ is quasi-compact. As for 2): for any $a\in {0}\times \prod_{i\ge 2} A_i=\mathfrak m_1$, $fa=0\in \mathfrak m$. So $a\in\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m_1\subseteq \mathfrak m$. Hence equality.